# Python3, convert list of array to purely array of float

Tags: arrays, list, python-3.x, numpy

I have a rolling window function. It converts a numpy array to list of arrays. However, I want to convert the results of this function to purely array.

```
import numpy as np

def get_rolling_window(arr, window):
    arr_rolled = [arr[i:i+window] for i in np.arange(arr.shape[0])]
    return arr_rolled

x = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
x_rolled = get_rolling_window(x, 2)
```

now x_rolled is a list of arrays. If I use

```
x_arr = np.array(x_rolled)
```

It will not work, because the dtype of x_arr is object, not float or int. And if you

```
print(x_arr.shape)
```

you will get (5,). For a pure array of float, its shape should be (5,2,2).

Do you know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: What does `np.concatenate(x_rolled)` give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `x_rolled` is a list of arrays of different shapes.  So `np.array` cannot turn it into a multdimensional array of ints.

```
In [235]: x_rolled
Out[235]: 
[array([[0, 1],
        [2, 3]]), array([[2, 3],
        [4, 5]]), array([[4, 5],
        [6, 7]]), array([[6, 7],
        [8, 9]]), array([[8, 9]])]
In [236]: [x.shape for x in x_rolled]
Out[236]: [(2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2)]
```

If I omit the last element, I get a 3d array:

```
In [237]: np.array(x_rolled[:-1])
Out[237]: 
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[2, 3],
        [4, 5]],

       [[4, 5],
        [6, 7]],

       [[6, 7],
        [8, 9]]])
In [238]: _.shape
Out[238]: (4, 2, 2)
```

which can easily be cast as float

```
np.array(x_rolled[:-1]).astype(float)
```

I suspect your roll function is not working as you want.